# How to remove portal header in websphere portal

Tags: websphere, portal, websphere-portal

Can anyone help me out in this, I have configured and deployed portlet application in my web-sphere portal server successfully [image]  .But the portal banner is displaying @Headerpart (shown arrow mark ). 
How can i remove the banner.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying you want to remove that entire black rectangle (including the menu and the search box stuff), but keep the sub menu (tabs in your screenshot lableed "Getting Started" and "Features")?

Comment: @online_p yes.i want the same

Answer (score 1):

That header section is a part of Portal's out of the box theme. You should read the documentation on how to customize the theme. If I'm not mistaken that looks like Portal 7 using the PageBuilder2 theme. [This link](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20WebSphere%20Portal%207%20Product%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Designing_and_setting_up_a_portal_site_wp7&content=pdcontent) should help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the instructions for customizing the navigation: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Supplemental+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Customizing_navigation_sdoc&content=pdcontent

Personally, I would remove the nav reference fromt eh theme_en.html file in the static resources. Then I'd create a side nav for the tab menu you want to retain. Here's the instructions for the side nav: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Create_a_basic_side_navigation_for_7.0.0.2

But that's just me, you may find it easier to customize the main nav.